# I want a new line to be made with number when using word wrap in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqpfE.png)

I am using word wrap to break large lines, but i want to make a new line number instead of using the same number for many lines because when i am trying to move the cursor with arrows, when is on the same line it goes even further. If you see the picture i want to goes as:lines 19,20,21

Comment: add new line characters where appropriate

Comment: Line wraping doesn't work like that. Its an editor feature, not a formatting tool, in other words; the VS Code feature **"word-wrap"** will not do what you are asking for. Don't get all hot and bothered yet though, not all is lost, there are plenty of tools out there that can break lines for you. These tools are called code formatting tools. I could recomend one, however; you failed to include the language that you are writing. They are not hard to find though, most languages have 1 or 2 that are much more popular than others.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode word wrap only changes the way your code is being displayed, not the actual file content.

If you want to format the code into several lines, your best solution would be to use a code formatter. HTML formatting is supported out of the box in VSCode.

To do this, in your settings.json (`Ctrl + P` and type `>Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` in the command palette) add `"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned"`, after which go back into your .html file and select `Format Document` in the right click menu.

Answer (score 0):

[before i click enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGvVn.png)

Thank your for your response, the truth is that your advices helped me a lot and 90% works. Sometimes it does not,  i uploaded the picture just to show you why and i am not requesting an answer. On the image if i click enter and break the line 119 everything works great.

Thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).